# example function and operator >=

Tags: c, stm32

I read this code:

```
static bool time_expired(uint16_t time, uint16_t start_time, uint16_t tmo)  {
    if (time >= start_time) {
        return (time - start_time) >= tmo;
    } else {
        return time + (0xFFFF - start_time) >= tmo; 
    }   
}
```

Now, I do not understand how it works. I don't understand the 
           `return (time - start_time) >= tmo;`
because the operator >= is for "Greater than or equal to".

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: I think that it means that the time elapsed is bigger than the tiemeout, so the time has expired.

Comment: i don't understand return (time - start_time) >= tmo; what's returns the function?

Comment: Look at it!   It returns a bool!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expressions

```
(time - start_time) >= tmo
```

and

```
time + (0xFFFF - start_time) >= tmo
```

are of type bool; in either case, a boolean value is returned, which matches the return type of the function.

However, as far as I know, C does not provide a separate boolean type; perhaps the language is C++.

Comment: C has `bool` in stdbool.h.

Comment: Indeed it does but the relational operators return 1 or 0 in C. If you make your answer more concrete in this respect, I'll upvote it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, my C knowledge is rusting away as years are passing by without using it.

Comment: Don't you have it the wrong way around? "[A] boolean value is returned, which matches the return type" – no, the result of the comparison is a Boolean, which then gets cast to the return type. The code would do the same with `int time_expired(..` or `double time_expired(..`.

Comment: Yes, but the answer was more to be understood as 'the function has a signature which states that its return type is bool, and the return statements evaluate expressions which actually and obviously match this stated return type'.

Answer (score 1):

`(time - start_time) >= tmo` is either 1 or 0 in C. It has an `int` type.